# What is the search order of \includegraphics?

Tags: graphics

There are multiple ways to modify how `\includegraphics` looks up the image file to include. I am interested in `\DeclareGraphicsExtensions` and `\graphicspath`.

What is `\includegraphics` search algorithm? Will it search

```
foreach extension in {<ext-list>}
    foreach directory in {<dir-list>}
```

, or `foreach directory ... foreach extension`?

... or does it even seach in parallel?

I am asking because I often end up converting images as part of a Makefile before the actual LaTeX run. I also never provide file-extensions in my `\includegraphics` statements. I am not happy with my Makefile's current procedure and like to optimise it. To do that I need to know how `\includegraphics` does its search.

Ultimately I'd like to have a directory with all my image source files and another directoy with all the converted/manipulated images. I want to make sure that `\includegraphics` will always look first in the directory with all the convertees for a matching file name and then look in the directory of source files, if it didn't find a match in the convertee-dir.

So for any answer there is the additional question: Is this behaviour stable or subject to change?

Comment: Deducing from my observations, it's `foreach extention . . . for each directory . . . `.  How would one change that?

Comment: the behaviour has been stable since 1993 but I may adjust it a bit to cope better with files with multiple dots or spaces, it wouldn't affect the ordering given in my answer though.

Comment: if you know the file extension it's quite a bit quicker to supply it than not, and similarly to resting the extensions to the ones that you know are used.

Answer (score 6):

If no extension is supplied then it tries each extension in turn to see if that file exists (using LaTeX's standard `\IfFileExists` test).

so if the file extensions (in the list `\Gin@extensions` as set via the command  `\DeclareGraphicExtensions`) are `.png`, `.jpg`,`.pdf` and 
if list `\input@path` as set by `\graphispath` is `{aaa/}{bbb/}`
and you do

`\includegraphics{foo}`

It will test in order using `\IfFileExists`

`foo.png`, `foo.jpg` then `foo.pdf`, stopping as soon as a file is found.

`\IfFileExists{foo.png}`

tests in order

`foo.png`, `aaa/foo.png` and `bbb/foo.png`

and reports success as soon as a file is found by TeX's primitive `\openin` primitive.

In each case `\openin` will search first the current directory and then search the full TEXINPUT path as set in your `texmf.cnf` or equivalent miktex settings.

Depending on the settings this may involve searching the filesystem, or looking up the file in a pre-stored ls-r file using exactly the same logic as `\input`.

Comment: It may be worth noting that the order for the extensions is saved in `\Gin@extensions` and can be changed with `\DeclareGraphicExtensions`.

Comment: It would be nice if there were an option to swap the search order. As the OP, I need the extension-first search order. I often have two directories, one for coarse-resolution images and the other for fine-resolution counterparts.  In each directory, I may or may not have a PDF and/or PNG versions of each figure.  In some compile situations, I want to pick up coarse-resolution versions, in other situations, I want the fine-resolution versions.  For this reason, I don't specify file extensions for inclugragraphics and I need the extension-first search order.

Comment: @Ryo if I understand you correcly you should be able to put course first or fine first in the `\graphicspath`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That's what I do, but that fails to work in some cases because of the problem the OP describes. Suppose that `fine/myfig.pdf` is the original figure and `coarse/myfig.png` is the lightweight coarse version and that `\graphicspath` searches `coarse` first. The problem is that `includegraphics{myfig}` uses `fine/myfig.pdf` .  I can't change the search order of extensions because I prefer the PDF version if both PDF and PNG exist under the same directory.  In other words, my requirement is, search for `coarse/myfig.pdf` and `coarse/myfig.png` before `fine/myfig.pdf`.

Comment: @Ryo the logic is already pretty complicated (and slow) a long extension list and long graphics path can easily generate a _lot_ of attempted file acceses. You can always arrange that `./course` and `./fine` have _all_ the files needed (by copying or symlink images only in one resolution) then rather than worrying about search order have just _one_ of `course` or`fine` in graphics path, depending which you need.