# Strange order of reading files?

Tags: graphics, paths

Let us consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\includegraphics{photo}

\end{document}
```

I have in my working directory the file `photo.jpg`, but the result is:

[image]

where the graphic file was taken from `C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/pas-cv/photo.png`.

I know that is enough to call `photo.jpg`. My question is why LaTeX does not search the file with any matching extension in the working directory, but looks for it in a strange place?

Comment: the search order is by extension, so it will first look for pdf and then for png etc. If you want to force that the current directory is used, load it with `{./photo}`

Comment: Looks like it's explained in [graphics - What is the search order of \includegraphics? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/313468/what-is-the-search-order-of-includegraphics). --side note, I suspect the problem is actually unfixable because of how TeX search for files...

Comment: @UlrikeFischer So the rule of searching first in the working directory is broken for the graphics files, isn't it?

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke According to my understanding: not really, it's `for(extension...) for(directory...)` as explained in the link above.

Comment: no, you are not giving an extension, so LaTeX has to provide that, and so it searches for photo.pdf, then for photo.png, then for ... and for every search it follows the rule to look in the current directory first.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you! I understand now. BTW: the file in question is a good example of why a *.log file is our friend. :-)